# Show $\cosh ([0, \infty))=[1, \infty), \quad \sinh (\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

For $\cosh ([0, \infty))=[1, \infty)$

Given that cosh is strictly increasing in $[0, \infty)$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\cosh(x)=\infty}$ and continuous on $\mathbb R$ the according to some theorem which i do not know (but it must exist) then $[0, \infty) \mapsto [1, \infty)$.

Q1: What is the Theorem I'm looking for? Can't find it in my textbook.

Q2: Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

We have $ \cosh (0)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\cosh(x)=\infty}$. This gives $\cosh ([0, \infty)) \subseteq[1, \infty).$

Now let $y \in (1, \infty).$ The intermediate value theorem gives: there is $x \in (0, \infty)$ such that $ \cosh(x)=y.$

This shows that $\cosh ([0, \infty)) =[1, \infty).$